# getting wrong variable from checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, checkbox

I have a HTML table with checkboxs in it that will show rows from MYSQL database. 
problem is when i mark one of the rows to do something on it it gives me a wrong value but MYSQL code is running correctly and it updating the right row , 
I'm confused and couldn't figure what is the problem , it was working fine till an hour ago.
I have put echo function to see the result of value that each time it show zero for $i and array with zero address,but MYSQL UPDATE code get's the right value and update the correct row.

HTML table :

```
<?php
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
        $db = mysql_select_db('table', $connection);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");
        mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_persian_ci'"); 


        /* Inbox section */
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE editor='' && status='Under Review' ", $connection);

            $string = '';

            if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
            $_SESSION["count"]=mysql_num_rows($query);
            ?>

        <form method="POST" action="">
        <table cellspacing='0' width="800"  border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lirstname</th>
                <th>Article Title</th>
                <th>Article File</th>
                <th>Reviewer Email Address</th>
                <th>Mark</th>

            </tr>

        <?php   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>



            <tr>
                <td align='center'><input type='text' name='title[]' id='title' value= "<? echo $row['title']; ?>" ></td>
                <td align='center'><input type='text' name='fname[]' id='fname' value= "<? echo $row['fname']; ?>" ></td>
                <td align='center'><input type='text' name='lname[]' id='lname' value= "<? echo $row['lname']; ?>" ></td>
                <td align='center'><input type='text' name='mastitle[]' id='mastitle'  value= "<? echo $row['mstitle']; ?>"></td>
                <td align='center'><input type='text' name='file[]' id='file' value="<? echo $row['msfile']; ?> "></td>
                <td align='center'><input type='text' name='editoremail[]' id='editoremail' ></td>
                <td align="center"><inputtype="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>

            </tr>               
      <?php } ?>

            </table>
            <div class='cleaner h10'></div>
            <input type='submit' name='send' id='send' value='Send'>
        </form>
```

php code :

```
 <?php
        // Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
        if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] == 'Send')
         {


            for($i=0;$i<=$_SESSION["count"];$i++)
            {
                if(isset($_REQUEST['checkbox'][$i]))
                    {
                        $set_id = $_REQUEST['checkbox'][$i];

                        $sql_new=mysql_query(" UPDATE `article` SET  `editor`='SENT'  WHERE `id`='$set_id' ", $connection);
                    echo $i;
                    echo "<br>" .   $article=$_REQUEST['file'][$i];
                    echo "<br>" .   $TOmail=$_REQUEST['editoremail'][$i];
                    echo "<br>" .   $manutitle=$_REQUEST['mastitle'][$i];

                    }   
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your checkbox and input fields are not mapped properly in php code. checkbox[1] will not always refers to tilte[1], fname[1]...etc.      Use checkbox name like name="checkbox[<? echo $loop_counter; ?>]" where $loop_counter will have value 0, 1, 2...

Comment: if i do that how should i check which one is the one that i've selected and what should i put insted of { WHERE `id`='$set_id' } in mysql query code ?

Comment: you have to change only your this line of code                                    $set_id = $_REQUEST['checkbox'][$i]; I can do this if u tell me business logic of  $_SESSION["count"].

Comment: $_SESSION["count"] is for counting the number of available rows , I've added it at the top of codes .

Comment: Sidenote: If you don't have `session_start();` loaded in all pages using sessions, add it (required). I don't see it in your code. @anonymox

Comment: I have updated your code..Please check

Comment: @Fred-ii- SESSION_START is at the top of my page I haven't showed it in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$row_counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' name='title[]' id='title' value= "<? echo $row['title']; ?>" ></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' name='fname[]' id='fname' value= "<? echo $row['fname']; ?>" ></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' name='lname[]' id='lname' value= "<? echo $row['lname']; ?>" ></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' name='mastitle[]' id='mastitle'  value= "<? echo $row['mstitle']; ?>"></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' name='file[]' id='file' value="<? echo $row['msfile']; ?> "></td>
        <td align='center'><input type='text' name='editoremail[]' id='editoremail' ></td>
        <td align="center"><inputtype="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="<? echo $row['id'].'_'.$row_counter++; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>                
 <?php } ?>
```

### business logic code...

```
            $a_set_id = explode('_', $_REQUEST['checkbox'][$i]);
            $set_id   = $a_set_id[0];
            $row_no   = $a_set_id[1];

            $sql_new=mysql_query(" UPDATE `article` SET  `editor`='SENT'  WHERE `id`='$set_id' ", $connection);
            echo $i;
            echo "<br>" .   $article=$_REQUEST['file'][$row_no];
            echo "<br>" .   $TOmail=$_REQUEST['editoremail'][$row_no];
            echo "<br>" .   $manutitle=$_REQUEST['mastitle'][$row_no];
```

Comment: thanks in advance, can you explain a bit about what have you done ?

Comment: Now checkbox store two information, db_table_row_id and form_table_row_counter, seprated by "_" .Is that working..

Comment: I've faced another problem with the code that you fixed, if there were one row or record your code won't work, and $article and $TOmail & $manutitle variables value is empty. but if number of records goes more than one it'll work , the exact problem is that your code won't count the first row and it'll start to count records after the first one , what should i do ?

Comment: what is value of $row_no in this case)....It should be "0", and what kind value $_REQUEST has in this case. Its not like $_REQUEST['file']=array('value') ?